# Benefits of separate AWS RDS Instances for each customer

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, backend, amazon-rds, web-development-server

I'm working on a project for a web app where each enterprise customer will have separate resources independent to themselves (i.e. users and user data unique to a single paying customer, content unique for each paying customer, etc). It's somewhat similar to a normal CRM. We're building on AWS and planning to use RDS for the database. Given the fact that each customer does not share data across any different region, would it be most effective to:

1. Upon enterprise customer sign up, a new VPC is created with new RDS and EC2 instances, so that each customer has siloed databased and services
2. Have a single VPC with RDS and EC2 instances shared across all customers and use an indicator field in the database to determine what data belongs to each customer

We don't anticipate having over 10000 users for any given enterprise customer, and right now the project is small with only a single enterprise customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer all depends on how you anticipate your application growth (not just in terms of number of customers but also performance), however personally I would say if you have a single enterprise customer at the moment create a single VPC.

Perhaps separate out a seperate database on the RDS for each customer initially assuming that cost would become a concern, with a seperate db user for each customer to limit exposure.

If the financials allow then you would look at separating out to a seperate RDS database where the performance demands (maybe you have tiers for SLAs etc).

If you get larger customers (who may have bespoke needs, or stringent requirements such as no multi tenant hosts) I would suggest you look at an organizations setup with a account per large customer to separate out the resources and a single account for any shared or multi-customer resources.

The key is plan ahead for how you would want to but if you're still in the early midst of onboarding clients then do not over complicate your setup yet.